# perforce how to cleanup a file opened on a non-existent client and non-existent workspace

Tags: perforce

Title says it all.

There's a file that perforce thinks it is opened in exclusive mode by a user on a given workspace and a given changelist, but neither the workspace nor the changelist exists.  The workspace was force deleted by an admin, the file mysteriously disappeared from the changelist and then we removed all other files from it and deleted it.

File still shows as being opened and locked by that user on that workspace on that changelist.

Most likely corrupted perforce database, possible solution here, as replied on the perforce forums: https://kb.perforce.com/AdminTasks/BackupAndRecovery/RarelyUsedSe..ommandFlags/P4dXxFlag

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how your admin removed the workspace? [According to the documentation](https://kb.perforce.com/AdminTasks/SuperuserTasks/RevertingFil..serOrClient), deleting a workspace should automatically revert any files, but leave the local files on the file system, which should be straight forward enough to delete.

If the issue is merely that the file remains locked, then a simple:

```
p4 unlock -f <file>
```

issued by an administrator, should resolve the problem.

Comment: admin did "p4 client -f -d <workspace>" and the file is still stuck.

Comment: that should totally do the trick... are you guys running a p4 proxy or anything else kooky like that, or are you operating on the main repository? Might be time to raise a ticket with Perforce...

Comment: waiting for p4 unlock -f

Comment: Doesn't do it, perforce claims "file is not opened in that changelist", which I assume is the default changelist.  Asking admin to add '-c changelist#' but as that changelist doesn't exist I don't have my hopes up.

Comment: Most likely corrupted perforce database, possible solution here, as replied on the perforce forums: https://kb.perforce.com/AdminTasks/BackupAndRecovery/RarelyUsedSe..ommandFlags/P4dXxFlag

Comment: Sounds like it might be time to call Perforce!

Answer (score 0):

I had this flag setting after moving a depot to a new server, which I don't recommend.

I created the User back on the new system.
I was able to see the old workspace, which was previously hidden because of filters.
Right click on the workspace, choose edit, and under the advanced tab there is a Host field, that I changed to match the current hostname (including the port - newhost:1666).
Set the connection to the user / workspace
Now the check mark was red, instead of blue.
I selected each marked file, right clicked and chose Resolve by the default safe mode. I forget if the icon changed.
Then I right-clicked and chose Revert if Unchanged, and the icon went back to a "file synced" blue dot. Done.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an inconsistency between the server's db.locks and db.working tables -- deleting the workspace must have deleted the db.working entries but not the db.locks entries (they're always supposed to be one-to-one).

From the server side there are a couple of options to fix this:

```
p4d -xx db.working db.locks
p4d -jr jnl.fix
```

or:

```
p4d -xf 925
```

It's also possible to go through some gyrations to fix it from the client side:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=CLIENT_NAME  (where this is the name of the deleted workspace)
p4 client
p4 sync FILE_NAME
p4 edit FILE_NAME
p4 revert FILE_NAME
p4 sync #none
p4 client -d CLIENT_NAME
```

i.e. re-create the opened file state (same depot file and same client name, so that the keys will match), and then revert it so the entries can get cleaned up properly.

Comment: with 2nd suggestion, On the same client, when p4 edit , it says file already opened in other cient [which is the same client]